# What exactly does extend in Typescript do?

Tags: typescript, material-ui, typescript-generics

I'm a php developer and am trying to learn js/typescript/react lately.
I've stumbled upon a few issues that I didn't quite understand.
So I make this thread with the hope that some experienced people will help me out.

## #1 Generic function with mongoose model as generic type

### Description

I write a generic function that returns all properties of a schema except for _id and __v.
After a few tries, I was able to make it work, here's my code:

```ts
// model
import mongoose, { Schema, Document } from 'mongoose'

export interface IGenre extends Document {
  name: string,
  description: string,
  createdDate: Date,
  updatedDate: Date
}

const GenreSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, default: '' },
  description: { type: String, default: '' },
  createdDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  updatedDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
})

export default mongoose.models['Genre'] || mongoose.model<IGenre>('Genre', GenreSchema)

// generic function returning props of model
import { Model } from 'mongoose'

const getSchemaProps = <S extends Model<S>>(s: S): string[] => {
  return Object.keys(s.schema.paths).filter(p => p !== '_id' && p !== '__v')
}

export {
  getSchemaProps,
}
```

### What I don't understand

The part I don't understand is `<S extends Model<S>>`.
Doesn't this create some kind of a loop?
Like S extends Model, but the S inside Model extends Model as well, according to my understanding, which results in `S extends Model<S extends Model<S....>>`
I didn't look up google for this solution, just applied random changes and it worked without throwing any errors!

### Question

Why doesn't this line of code throw error?

```ts
<S extends Model<S>>
```

## #2 Type extending with assigned value

### Description

When looking up the type definition file of material ui component, there was a syntax I couldn't understand.

```ts
// <system_path>\node_modules\@mui\x-data-grid\models\colDef\gridColDef.d.ts
export declare type GridColumns<R extends GridValidRowModel = any> = GridEnrichedColDef<R>[]
```

`GridValidRowModel` is defined in this file below

```ts
// <system_path>\node_modules\@mui\x-data-grid\models\gridRows.d.ts
export declare type GridValidRowModel = {
    [key: string]: any;
};
```

### What I don't understand

I read typescript doc, maybe I missed it but I just can't find anywhere explaining this syntax:

```ts
GridColumns<R extends GridValidRowModel = any> // (1)
```

If I have to guess the `GridValidRowModel = any` part assigns a default any type to `GridValidRowModel`, which makes (1) equivalent to this:

```ts
GridColumns<R extends any>
```

But in `gridRows.d.ts` `GridValidRowModel` is clearly defined as an Object with key:value properties.

### Question

What does this syntax mean?

```ts
ISomeInterface<T extends A = B>
```

What type of R is in the code above?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are parsing the generics wrong - I have added paranthesis for emphasis

What you read is

```
ISomeInterface<T extends (A = B)>
```

What Typescript reads is

```
ISomeInterface<(T extends A) = B>
```

That means that

```
GridColumns<R extends GridValidRowModel = any>
```

is equivalent to

```
GridColumns<any>
```

Note that 'any' does not mean an empty object but rather something that will fulfill any class checks - 'any' will extend everything!